# ZF Frontend and backend routing

Tags: zend-framework, routes

I want something that sounds fairly simple to me but appears not to be.

My problem is that I need 2 routes voor my application:

Whenever the module is admin apply the following route:

```
$router->addRoute(
            'backend',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:module/:controller/:action/:id/:value', array('module' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index', 'id' => ':id', 'value' => ':value'))
        );
```

Which works great. An example url could be: `http://localhost/server/domains/demo/admin/images/album/3` where admin is the module, images the controller and so on.

All I want is that when a user goes to `http://localhost/server/domains/demo` he is redirected to the `default module`, `index controller` and `index action`. Everything after `demo/` should be considered a single parameter (with unknown `/` possible).

I tried several things, from using `Route_Regex`, trying `(.*)` or `(\d+)`, things I found all around online. Tried switching values, making them static, turning on/off `removeDefaultRouter`, but nothing worked. Below you can see my current bootstrap. Any ideas?

```
$router = $this->frontController->getRouter();
    $router->removeDefaultRoutes();
    $router->addRoute(
        'backend',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/admin/:controller/:action/:id/:value', array('module' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index', 'id' => ':id', 'value' => ':value'))
    );

    $router->addRoute(
        'frontend',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/default/:controller/:action/(.*)', array('module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'))
    );
```

Backend works fine, but whenon the `http://localhost/server/domains/demo/` I get the following error: `No route matched the request`

When given an answer, please explain why, because Zend_Route has always been a little vague for me. Thanks in advance!

**Temp fix**

Below the temporary fix that I use. It works exactly how I want, but I still believe that the same is achievable with Zend_Route without checking if the module is admin.

```
$router = $this->frontController->getRouter();
    $uri = explode('demo/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $uri = (isset($uri[1])) ? explode('/', $uri[1]) : $uri[0];
    if($uri[0] == 'admin')
    {
        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:module/:controller/:action/:id/:value', array('module' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index', 'id' => null, 'value' => null));
        $router->addRoute('router', $route);
    }
    else
    {
        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/*', array('module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'));
        $router->addRoute('router', $route);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is worth doing if you really have to use this routes. For normal usage you can just generate links by

```
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->Url(array('module' => 'admin'));
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->Url(array('module' => 'default'));
```

and so on.

If you are not ok with this, try routes chaining:

```
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();

    $dispatcher = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getDispatcher();
    $request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();
    $frontRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module(array(), $dispatcher, $request);
    $backRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module(array('module' => 'admin'), $dispatcher, $request);

    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('admin');
    $router->addRoute('backend', $route->chain($backRoute));

    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('default');
    $router->addRoute('frontend', $route->chain($frontRoute));
```

Explenation:
`Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module` is for definining modules routes for the application. By chaining it to normal route like `new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('admin')` you made links like /admin/[your_module_route] where [your_module_route] have defined defaults `array('module' => 'admin')` and can take other parameters too.
`new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module(array(), $dispatcher, $request);` is defined as an default route on the standard router.

Comment: Hi, thanks for yout response. I don't understand precisely how this Route_Module works, and can't find it in the docs. Could you explain a bit better what you did?

This works for the first part, but it breaks my :id and :value in my route (like I had), and I can't add any values (like demo/anyvalue) for the frontend. Could you help me out here (or explain a bit more about the code above so I can tr y stuff for myself?)

Comment: `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module` is for definining modules routes for the application. By chaining it to normal route like `new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('admin')` you made links like /admin/[your_module_route] where [your_module_route] have defined defaults 'module' => 'admin' and can take other parameters too.



`new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module(array(), $dispatcher, $request);` is defined as an default route on the standard router.

Comment: It is not completely clear yet, but I'm getting there. I tried adding `$backRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module(array('module' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index', 'id' => ':id', 'value' => ':value'), $dispatcher, $request);` but this won't recognize the id and value from the url. ALso tried adding it to the `$route` Can you give me the code that works for the backend, like the normal route, maybe then I can figure the rest out.

Comment: If you want additional parameters and other defaults define it here `new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('admin')`.

Comment: I tried that, `$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('admin/:controller/:action/:id/:value', array('controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index', 'id' => ':id', 'value' => ':value'));` will give me an `Invalid controller specified (index)` error, while it should be looking for dashboard as default...

Comment: Currently I have this: `$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:module/:controller/:action/:id/:value', array('module' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index', 'id' => ':id', 'value' => ':value'));
  $router->addRoute('backend', $route->chain($backRoute));
  
  $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:module/:controller/:action/*', array('module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'));
  $router->addRoute('frontend', $route->chain($frontRoute));`

This works perfectly for the default, but it overwrites my admin path and goes to default

Comment: Added temporary fix to the question